# Standard deviation in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, standard-deviation

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.std(np.array([0,1])))
```

it produces `0.5`

I am confident that this is incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is correct. `std = RMS(data - mean)`. In this case: `std = sqrt((0.5^2 + 0.5^2) / 2) = sqrt(0.25) = 0.5`

Comment: @MadPhysicist, thank you, I just got a bit confused with sample and population std. Google spreadsheet uses sample standard deviation under stdev.

Comment: Set the optional `ddof` parameter to `1` to get the population std: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html

Comment: BTW thanks for that import at the top. Most people leave it out making their code harder to copy-n-paste into the console.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

By default, [`numpy.std`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) returns the population standard deviation, in which case `np.std([0,1])` is correctly reported to be `0.5`. If you are looking for the sample standard deviation, you can supply an optional `ddof` parameter to `std()`:

```
>>> np.std([0, 1], ddof=1)
0.70710678118654757
```

`ddof` modifies the divisor of the sum of the squares of the samples-minus-mean. The divisor is `N - ddof`, where the default `ddof` is `0` as you can see from your result.

Comment: I think default of numpy is `population` standard deviation, which is N and sample standard deviation is N-1.

Comment: I admit that my terminology may be backwards.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Hmm, I must be missing something, but on wikipedia, the version of ddof=0 is called "sample standard deviation". And the case of ddof=1 means "In that case the result of the original formula would be called the sample standard deviation. Dividing by n − 1 rather than by n gives an unbiased estimate of the variance of the larger parent population. This is known as Bessel's correction.". In your answer, I think you have it backwards.

Comment: OK, this is as confusing as it can get, since the same term ("sample standard deviation") is used for two opposite things. Contrary to the article about Standard deviation, the article about Bessel correction says *"This correction is so common that the term "sample variance" and "sample standard deviation" are frequently used to mean the corrected estimators (unbiased sample variation, less biased sample standard deviation), using n − 1."*.

Comment: Either the interpretation is "standard deviation used when you only have samples" or "the standard deviation of the samples". But what is *not* ambiguous, I think, is the term "population standard deviation". And numpy doesn't return that, but the standard deviation of the samples (i.e the uncorrected).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb. Would you mind making the correction? It has been a long time since I wrote this answer, and at this point I think you are much better versed in the terminology than I am. The only thing I was really able to understand unambiguously from your explanation is why I have always been confused by the terms :)